# Encoding of Console.Read

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, console

I am currently developing an application that takes input from the console *but also supports input redirection*. For this, I usually use `Console.Read` to receive a single character. However, I cannot find any resource that states what encoding it uses (ASCII? UTF-16? UTF-8? <random codepage>?), and `Console.InputEncoding` seems to only affect direct input from the console. What encoding does it use, and how could I change that if at all possible?

**EDIT:** The text file is encoded in UTF-8, but I just want to know how it will be read.

Comment: It is the encoding that the other program uses, the one whose output you redirected to your input.  If it is a text file then it is whatever text encoding that was used by the program that created the file.  So you just don't know unless you have hard facts about that program or file.  The fact that it is so unguessable makes I/O redirection a major bug factory, you'll be much better off not relying on it.  It is a Unix feature that should have stayed in Unix :)

Comment: No idea.  Why the upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't recieve much of a response, I decided to do some testing myself. I wrote a UTF-8 file with various byte widths:

```
0123456789: Basic Latin, 1 byte
٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩: Arabic, 2 bytes
₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉: Superscripts and Subscripts, 3 bytes
: Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols, 4 bytes
```

For those who can't read it properly, here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3a20 4261 7369  0123456789: Basi
0000010: 6320 4c61 7469 6e2c 2031 2062 7974 650a  c Latin, 1 byte.
0000020: d9a0 d9a1 d9a2 d9a3 d9a4 d9a5 d9a6 d9a7  ................
0000030: d9a8 d9a9 3a20 4172 6162 6963 2c20 3220  ....: Arabic, 2 
0000040: 6279 7465 730a e282 80e2 8281 e282 82e2  bytes...........
0000050: 8283 e282 84e2 8285 e282 86e2 8287 e282  ................
0000060: 88e2 8289 3a20 5375 7065 7273 6372 6970  ....: Superscrip
0000070: 7473 2061 6e64 2053 7562 7363 7269 7074  ts and Subscript
0000080: 732c 2033 2062 7974 6573 0af0 9d9f 8ef0  s, 3 bytes......
0000090: 9d9f 8ff0 9d9f 90f0 9d9f 91f0 9d9f 92f0  ................
00000a0: 9d9f 93f0 9d9f 94f0 9d9f 95f0 9d9f 96f0  ................
00000b0: 9d9f 973a 204d 6174 6865 6d61 7469 6361  ...: Mathematica
00000c0: 6c20 416c 7068 616e 756d 6572 6963 2053  l Alphanumeric S
00000d0: 796d 626f 6c73 2c20 3420 6279 7465 730a  ymbols, 4 bytes.
```

Now, I wrote a simple program to just output the codepoints it read:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Codepoints:");
        for (int cur = Console.Read(); cur != -1; cur = Console.Read())
            Console.WriteLine("U+{0:X4}", cur);
    }
}
```

Now, here is the output when run on my test file:

```
Codepoints:
U+0030
U+0031
U+0032
U+0033
U+0034
U+0035
U+0036
U+0037
U+0038
U+0039
<cut>
U+0660
U+0661
U+0662
U+0663
U+0664
U+0665
U+0666
U+0667
U+0668
U+0669
<cut>
U+2080
U+2081
U+2082
U+2083
U+2084
U+2085
U+2086
U+2087
U+2088
U+2089
<cut>
U+D835
U+DFCE
U+D835
U+DFCF
U+D835
U+DFD0
U+D835
U+DFD1
U+D835
U+DFD2
U+D835
U+DFD3
U+D835
U+DFD4
U+D835
U+DFD5
U+D835
U+DFD6
U+D835
U+DFD7
<cut>
```

(As I suspected, adding `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` had no effect on the output.) As you see, it reads characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane just fine. However, when you start going into supplementary planes, it acts like UTF-16 and starts outputting surrogate characters. However, these surrogates still encode the original characters correctly, which led me to my conclusion:

**`Console.Read` can read UTF-8, but outputs in UTF-16.**